# ExtJS Grid rowdblclick and rowclick events : getting the row data

Tags: extjs6

Why `rowclick` have a `record` parameter to get the data from the clicked row and `rowdblclick` have not?

```
rowdblclick : function(grid, index, e){     

},

rowclick: function(grid, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {      

},
```

How can I get the record data from a double clicked row?

Comment: Never mind: `grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected()[0].data`. Strange way to see things... both have `grid` parameter....

Comment: I mean `grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].data`

Comment: What do you mean [rowdblclick](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#event-rowdblclick) doesn't have a record param?

Comment: @scebotari: You're correct. All people must start to respect param list in all exemples. (and some dumb people must start to read the F manual .. ). Can you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, [according to the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#event-rowdblclick), the *rowdblclick* event passes a record param to the listener functions.

Comment: Mea Culpa. `http://docs.sencha.com` is now in my browser's favorite list.